# Wheeler’s delayed choice experiment — why can’t a photon select state multiple times?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I have a question regarding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%27s_delayed-choice_experiment. I am interested in knowing why quantum mechanics seems to be so fixated in thinking that photons in a delayed slit experiment must have already selected a state prior to to the final measurement configuration.

The article says there’s not enough time for a physical process to notify the photon that the conditions will change, but why can’t it just REACT to the slits in real time, what points to this being an ATOMIC SINGLE operation where the photon can decide this only once?

What proof is there that an photon must have decided its final state already at the point it’s created, why can’t it just be in a random discrete state at creation (ie 50% particle, 50% wave) and every time it goes through two slits it gets converted to a wave and vice versa, (through some physical process when interacting with the polarizers or something) until it reaches its goal where we observe its final state?

In other words considering that we can see the results only at the end what proof is there that the photon doesn’t just react to what it’s encountering?

Thanks so much for enlightening me.

Edit: Corrected electron to photon.

Comment: I guess I want to know in general why quantum mechanics thinks matter is in an undefined state until measured where it then collapses to a discrete state, when surely measuring itself alters the state. Why can’t it just be that matter exposes dual properties, is always one of the states and specific interactions just alter which one they are in currently? Or is this a terminology thing where undefined doesn’t mean a superstate but just random?

Comment: I think you are digging at what is called the Measurement Problem, and it is a major conundrum in modern physics.  But there is never a case where a quantum particle is "50% wave, 50% particle." Superposition of states means it is (say) a 50/50 probability of being spin up or down, or some other property or location.  If you have to choose a mental model, it's better to say that the nature is always wavelike. What we call a particle is a very localized wave

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what proof is there that this is a superposition, and not just a 50/50 shot which becomes clear at measurement, which in turn can affect the outcome?

Comment: the "proof" is they Feynman path integral. To get from A to B, the photon takes all possible paths, or at least, the amplitude is the sum phase amplitude of the action of all possible paths.

Answer (score 0):

In general Wheeler’s experiment was about photons not electrons. And the implications about it are still debated, so not to worry.

If you can picture an excited electron in an atom (or in an electrode) then there is good reason to believe that it is already interacting with the EM field even before emission … scientists use the term virtual photons to refer to forces in EM field. In general all electrons in all the atoms in an apparatus are interacting with this excited electron … thru the EM field … the EM field rules it all.

A photon always has its wave and particle properties, as does the electron … it’s the slits that reveal the wave nature but it does not mean there is no particle nature … I think that’s what a lot of scientists miss. For example the electron is always a particle but because it reacts with the EM field we can see wave properties.

Comment: Apparently it was still possible to edit the question so I fixed it as I meant to write photon all along, thanks for pointing it out. What I can’t believe is time travel shenanigans or even understand the need for such an explanation, when in reality the polarizers surely interact with the photons. Why is it gospel that this has to be decided at time 0 when surely we can’t measure any of this without altering the state again, no? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @TGGR yes lot's of shenanigans .... there is no faster than light nonsense possible .... Scientific American loves a good headline and researchers love getting their grants.  Yes the EM of the polarizers is working with the EM field of the photon etc etc.

Comment: @TGGR No disagreement with PhysicsDave's answer itself. But your comment about a photon interacting with a polarizer as an explanation for quantum effects needs a comment. I don't want to lead us astray, so I'll simply say it's the relationship of any polarizers near the slits that is important. That relationship (and other variables) can of course be changed midflight (what you might call real-time). There is no evidence that photons "must have already selected a state prior to to the final measurement configuration." In delayed choice experiments, you must examine the full final context.

Comment: Thank you all. This is what I can’t understand that physicians are postulating theories where electrons go back in time to select the final state, when I can’t find any reasoning why it can’t just happen in real time. There is clearly something I am missing for such a thought to even occur but I can’t find what that could be, as all texts seem to take it for granted that this must happen at time 0.

Comment: @TGGR, you're absolutely correct. Real-time manifestation is entirely plausible. In fact, it can be systematically deduced on a particle-by-particle basis, with each causal effect unfolding step by step. Embracing Occam's razor, there seems little reason to delve into the complexities of the wave function, which lacks a clear physical explanation. The entire process can unfold seamlessly and logically, just as you suggest, in real time.

Answer (score 0):

A photon's state is not self-selected, but it can be influenced by a slit or the edge of a slit, in three or four different ways. First, the photon may or may not be absorbed. Second, it may become polarized parallel to the slit or edge. Third, its trajectory is likely to be altered and sometimes its frequency may change when scattered. These effects collectively determine the timing, location, and probability of the photon hitting the target. So, while a photon's state can be changed, it initially starts in a specific state.

When considering a photon as a particle, envisioning an origin other than a specific initial state becomes challenging. The response to your question also depends on the interpretation of what constitutes a "state." To simplify this concept, think of throwing an axe towards a distant target. The axe's ability to securely embed itself in the target depends entirely on its state upon release. In this analogy, the axe represents the photon, and its rotation corresponds to its oscillation or frequency. The state of the photon is influenced by factors like its speed towards the target, the precise direction of its movement, the speed of its rotation, and the angle at which it was released. Also toward the bottom of the Wheeler's delayed-choice experiment introduction you linked it says single slits do not create interference, but that is not true. Single slits and single edges create interference patterns.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150566/discussion-on-answer-by-bill-alsept-wheelers-delayed-choice-experiment--why-ca); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Yes the slit material, the atoms/molecules of dielectric material (not metalic,transparent) must be part or cause  of the tremendous scattering that is observed when the photons exit .... but as you know I give the EM field and its Feynman like properties the full credit for the "interference".  The term diffraction for a photon in the DSE in my mind is a result of 2 processes then, 1) scattering and 2) Feynman paths.